# Store to PostgreSQL DB using Pig JDBC driver returns empty time in timestamp field

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, apache-pig

I am using JDBC Driver **postgresql9.3-1101.jdbc4.jar** to write to my postgres table field which is of type *timestamp*.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable(dt  timestamp NOT NULL);
```

I am using the Pig ToDate() Function to covert my string to datetime format.

```
toStore = FOREACH myRecord GENERATE ToDate(StatusDateTime,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') as dt;
```

Dump of **dt** in PIG shows up in ISO format with time value preserved however I am not sure why my time is reset to zero when I dump on Postgresql cmd window.

```
testdb=# SELECT * FROM myTable;
         dt          
---------------------
 2013-01-15 00:00:00
 2013-01-15 00:00:00
```

### UPDATES AFTER Using below command

```
INSERT INTO some_table (ts_column) VALUES (to_timestamp('2011-06-13 15:36:38', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'));
```

> java.io.IOException: JDBC Error at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.DBStorage$MyDBOutputFormat$1.commitTask(DBStorage.java:223)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter.commitTask(PigOutputCommitter.java:286)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.commit(Task.java:1014) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.done(Task.java:884) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:453) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262) Caused by:
>   java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO myTable(dt)
>   VALUES(to_timestamp('2013-01-15 12:34:00','YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') was
>   aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause. at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleErr

SameError if I use the other format

```
'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'
```

> localhost.localdomain java.io.IOException: JDBC Error at
>   org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.DBStorage$MyDBOutputFormat$1.commitTask(DBStorage.java:223)
>   at
>   org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter.commitTask(PigOutputCommitter.java:286)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.commit(Task.java:1014) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.done(Task.java:884) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:453) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1408)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262) Caused by:
>   java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO myTable(dt)
>   VALUES(to_timestamp('2013-01-15 12:34:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') was
>   aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause. at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleE

Comment: I don't know PIG, but in JDBC `java.sql.Date` does not have a time part (it get's removed, see the JavaDocs, it's documented there). Does PIG have a `toTimestamp()` funcion?

Comment: The ToDate works similar to Timestamp ( ToDate converts the ISO or the customized string or the Unix timestamp to the DateTime object.)

Comment: I even tried the below command in JDBC driver but it fails        INSERT INTO some_table 
 (ts_column) 
 VALUES 
 (to_timestamp('2011-06-13 15:36:38', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'));

Comment: "*it fails*" is not a valid Postgres error message

Comment: I have added the Error message above

Comment: Unfortunately your stacktrace does not contain the actual **Postgres** error message. What happens if you run that directly through SQL (e.g. in `psql`)